# Cannot select value using keyid in XML and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem showing the value in the table by using keyid. It shows false instead of the value that I wanted.The information that is found in these codes are just randomly generated.
This is my XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    <unit>
        <assessment_details>
            <assessment_item> idkey="1"
                <type>Assignment 1</type>
                <desc>Introductory HTML/XML/XSLT website</desc>
                <assess_value>20</assess_value>
            </assessment_item> idkey="2"
            <assessment_item>
                <type>Assignment 2</type>
                <desc>Advanced XMl/XSLT web application</desc>
                <assess_value>30</assess_value>             
            </assessment_item>
            <assessment_item> idkey="3"
                <type>Examination</type>
                <desc>End of semester examination</desc>
                <assess_value>50</assess_value>
            </assessment_item>
        </assessment_details>
        <student>
          <student_id>16390227</student_id>
          <sname>Battle</sname>
          <fname>Gillian</fname>
          <results>
                <stu_mark resultkeyid="1">12</stu_mark>
                <stu_mark resultkeyid="2">25</stu_mark>
                <stu_mark resultkeyid="3">30</stu_mark>
              </results>
          <final_mark> </final_mark>
          <final_grade> </final_grade>
        </student>
    </unit>
```

This is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>   
<h2>Student Results</h2>

   <table>
     <tr>
       <th>Student ID</th>
       <th>Surname</th>
       <th>Firstname</th>
       <th>Assign1</th>
       <th>Assign2</th>
       <th>Exam</th>
       <th>Final Mark</th>
       <th>Final Grade</th>
     </tr>

     <xsl:for-each select="unit/student">
     <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="student_id"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="sname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="fname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="resultkeyid='1'"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="resultkeyid='2'"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="resultkeyid='3'"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="final_mark"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="final_grade"/></td>
     </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the table, the values in assign1, assign2, and exam is 'false' instead of 12,25,30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="results/stu_mark[@resultkeyid = '1']"/>` and so on.

Comment: (Maybe add a short explanation? or is this really XSLT 101, as I spotted the same error immediately?)

Comment: I recently started to learn XML and XSLT with a little background in coding so minor mistakes are usually made. I also don't really remember all the syntax and the codes used in it.

Comment: @MikeJoe, your XSLT is fine as a start, but I would suggest you first take an tutorial on XPath as that is more important to be able to select the wanted data in the XML. The path `results/stu_mark` selects all `stu_mark` grand children of the `results` child of the `student` context node inside of the `for-each`, and then you can add a predicate in square brackets to select the element you want. In your attempt you had written a syntactically correct XPath expression, but one that evaluates to a boolean value.